# Find First Empty Element in a String Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to use this code to determine the value of `Firstcell` but can't get an output:

```
Sub FindFirstEmptyCell()

    Dim l As Integer
    Dim Firstcell As Integer
    Dim MyArray(5) As String
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    MyArray(1) = "g"
    MyArray(2) = "g"
    MyArray(3) = "s"
    MyArray(4) = ""
    MyArray(5) = "f"


    For l = 0 To 5
            currentRowValue = MyArray(l)
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) = True Or currentRowValue = "" Then
             Firstcell = l: Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "output" , do you mean you are not getting the expected result for the variable `Firstcell` ?

Comment: not clear what's your real aim: are you looking for the some first empty cell  in a `Range`?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you defined `Dim MyArray(5) As String` , which means `MyArray` has 6 elements, starting from `0` to `5`.
If you want to have 5 elements, change to `Dim MyArray(4) As String`.

So when setting strings to `MyArray`, you need to start from `MyArray(0) = "g"` , and so on...

Then, when running the code below, you need to remember that the array counter starts from `0`, and if you want to get a reference to a row in a worksheet, then you need to add `+1` , since there is no row `0`, and you will get an error.

```
Sub FindFirstEmptyCell()

    Dim l As Integer
    Dim Firstcell As Integer
    Dim MyArray(4) As String
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    MyArray(0) = "g"
    MyArray(1) = "g"
    MyArray(2) = "s"
    MyArray(3) = ""
    MyArray(4) = "f"

    ' loop through all elements in MyArray
    For l = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        If IsEmpty(MyArray(l)) Or MyArray(l) = "" Then
            Firstcell = l
            MsgBox "First empty element in MyArray is " & Firstcell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: just to throw in that by declaring the upper bound of an array only the lower bound is implicitly set to the ruling `Option Base`. This means that should `Option Base 1` be ruling then `MyArray(4)` is compiled as `MyArray(1 to 4). To override this default behavior just declare both lower and upper bounds (`MyArray(0 to 4)`).

Answer (score 0):

MyArray(0) is always "" by the looks of the code